# How can I justify equations?

Tags: equations

I want these equations be justified. How can I do that? I mean all equation started at the same margin. Can anyone help me?

S.t.

```
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{ng}^{min}-\alpha_{ng}^{max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}~~\forall g\in\phi^{G-n},\forall n\in\phi^N
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}-\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid SB(l)=n\\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}+\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid RB(l)=n\\
\end{equation}
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
&-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}\\
&+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}\nonumber\\
&+\delta_n^{min}-\delta_n^{max}=0~~\forall n\in \phi^n\\
\end{split}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also, please try to post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: OK. I will do that for my next question surely. Tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is for equations is to center them, and there are several way you can get the equations left aligned.

1. If you want *all* your equations left aligned you can use the `fleqn` option to the `amsmath` package:

   [image]

   Note that equations are aligned on the left but not flush with the margin. If you desire them further to the left you can adjust `\mathindent`.  For instance, to get them to be flush with the margin you can apply `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`:

   [image]
2. If you don't want *all* the equations to be left aligned then you could use the `flalign` environment for the ones which you desire to be left aligned.  This yields and output similar to the first image with the equations aligned to the left, but not flush with the margin.

   If you add a trailing `&` to at least one of the equations then you end up with the equations flush with the margin.
3. And, as egreg pointed out, you can also use the `align` (or `alignat`) environment which can be used to specify that the equations be left aligned. These won't be flush with the margin so the output will be as in the first image above.

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

---

## Code: `fleqn` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\MyEquations}{%
    \begin{equation}
    \alpha_{ng}^{min}-\alpha_{ng}^{max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}~~\forall g\in\phi^{G-n},\forall n\in\phi^N
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    \beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}-\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid SB(l)=n\\
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    \beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}+\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid RB(l)=n\\
    \end{equation}
    \begin{gather}
    \begin{split}
    &-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}\\
    &+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}\nonumber\\
    &+\delta_n^{min}-\delta_n^{max}=0~~\forall n\in \phi^n\\
    \end{split}
    \end{gather}%
}


\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|fleqn| option:
\MyEquations

\noindent
With \verb|fleqn| option and \verb|\mathindent=0pt|:
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\MyEquations
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|flalign| environment:
\begin{flalign}
&\alpha_{ng}^{min}-\alpha_{ng}^{max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}~~\forall g\in\phi^{G-n},\forall n\in\phi^N \\
&\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}-\gamma_{n}=0
\forall l\in\phi^L\mid SB(l)=n\\
&\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}+\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid RB(l)=n \\\nonumber
&-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}\\\nonumber
&+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}\\\nonumber
&+\delta_n^{min}-\delta_n^{max}=0~~\forall n\in \phi^n
\end{flalign}
Using \verb|flalign| environment
with a trailing \verb|&|:
\begin{flalign}
&\alpha_{ng}^{min}-\alpha_{ng}^{max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}~~\forall g\in\phi^{G-n},\forall n\in\phi^N &\\
&\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}-\gamma_{n}=0
\forall l\in\phi^L\mid SB(l)=n\\
&\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}+\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid RB(l)=n \\\nonumber
&-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}\\\nonumber
&+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}\\\nonumber
&+\delta_n^{min}-\delta_n^{max}=0~~\forall n\in \phi^n
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|align| environment:
\begin{align}
&\alpha_{ng}^{min}-\alpha_{ng}^{max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}~~\forall g\in\phi^{G-n},\forall n\in\phi^N \\
&\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}-\gamma_{n}=0
\forall l\in\phi^L\mid SB(l)=n\\
&\beta_l^{min}-\beta_l^{max}+\frac{\epsilon_l^{min}}{\beta_l}-\frac{\epsilon_l^{max}}{\beta_l}+\gamma_{n}=0~~\forall l\in\phi^L\mid RB(l)=n \\\nonumber
&-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{min}\\\nonumber
&+\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid SB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}-\sum_{\forall l \in\phi^l\mid RB(l)=n}\epsilon_l^{max}\\\nonumber
&+\delta_n^{min}-\delta_n^{max}=0~~\forall n\in \phi^n
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not simply `align`?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Can't believe I had missed the most obvious solution. :-)